# Periodical changes in Remote Host Identification (SSH) on CentOS 6

Tags: linux, ssh, puppet, centos6, foreman

I have this following error when I tried to connect using SSH:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that the RSA host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
14:44:d3:d7:ba:ba:6e:d2:a0:20:8f:9d:56:c6:d9:54.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/arinto/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending key in /home/arinto/.ssh/known_hosts:85
RSA host key for 10.0.109.37 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

Interestingly, after few seconds, I can connect normally. Which means, the remote host identification revert back to the one that I have in my `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

What's the root cause of this behaviour?

Here's the detail of my system:

- CentOS 6.7
- `uname -a` output: `Linux cat1.xxxx.xxx.xxx.xx 2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 22 22:00:00 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- Managed by Puppet 3.8.3 and Foreman
- The server is a [data node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html#data-node) in our Elasticsearch cluster. The Puppet also manages the Elasticsearch cluster.

**Update**:

What I've done so far:

- Examined `\var\log\messages`, but I did not find any suspicious message
- Inspected all the log files in `\var\log` that recently updated, but I did not find any suspicious message

Comment: You may be connecting to the load balanced hostname or the virtual ip-address of the cluster.  Rather than connecting directly to a specific node from that cluster you're connecting to alternating nodes. Does `dig hostname` correspond to the ip-address of your node?

Comment: "The server is a data node in our Elasticsearch cluster." - you are ssh'ing to a virtual ip address managed by  HAproxy probably - the MAC address is changing.

Comment: @HBruijn: `dig hostname` correponds to my node. I did ssh using the ip address.

Comment: @Rob-d: nope, there is no HAProxy in front of our Elasticsearch. Is it possible that internally, there's a process that changes the host key?

Comment: Does your `ssh` problem happen when `puppet` is running?  It may replace the host key file temporarily or something similar.

Comment: @chicks: I was suspecting this. But yesterday when I manually inspected, they are not happening in the same time. Thanks for the insight, I'll turn off `puppet` for these few hours and see how it goes.

Comment: I turned off `puppet` agent but the problem still appears. So, it's not related to `puppet`.

Comment: it's a cluster - it uses VIP - has to be - how many servers does elasticsearch span vs how many IP address are you ssh'ing to?

Comment: @Rob-d elasticsearch has 10 servers, each of them map to different static IP. We don't use any DHCP service to assign the IP.